# Tests work in Postman collection, but fails in newman

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, postman, newman

In postman collection runner everything works fine, all the request and test pass, when running with newman the same collection and environemt some of the test fail for no reasson. 
I am using newman v5.0.0, node v12.16.3, npm 6.14.4.
Command that I am using with newman : newman run collection.json -e environment.json

Screenshot for Newman:
[image: NEWMAN CLI]

Screenshot for postman:
[image: POSTMAN COLLECTION RUNNNER]

Comment: Could you provide more context about _what_ that request is doing and paste the error message you're seeing please, it's hard to see that in the image.

Comment: Its a GET request, getting the current user info that is logged in the system. The error message in NEWMAN is :expected response to have status code 200 but got 404 at assertion:0 in test-script , and as you can see in postman everything works fine....

Comment: Have you tried this with the `-k` flag?

Comment: Nope, didnt use -k flag. it should be like this "newman run collection.json -e environment.json -k " ?

Comment: It's worth a try :)

Comment: If the command is: newman run collection.json -e environment.json -k , then it didnt help. Still the same issue

Comment: With more details about how you're running this it's going to be difficult to provide an answer. There could be lots of reason why it's not working and we're seeing just a snapshot of what you can see. Feel free to raise this on the https://community.postman.com site and hopefully we can drill down to the issue more.

Comment: I raised the isssue on the community postman with more details about the error. Link: https://community.postman.com/t/tests-are-working-in-postman-collection-runner-but-fails-in-newman-cli/12643

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, newman v5.0.0 uses next generation URL processing, and when you install postman by default in Setting "Use next generation URL processing" is turned off and I couldn't see the errors in postman console. 
The errors were blank space after the URI request... Now is working fine :)